# How to display a MySQL database record only once when duplicates exist in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose my db looks like this:

```
id | person_id | hobby       | time
-----------------------------------
1  | 67        | golf        | mon
2  | 33        | reading     | tues
3  | 67        | baseball    | fri
4  | 67        | golf        | sun
```

I want to display a list of all the hobbies of person with id 67 on a page.

If I do this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hobbies WHERE person_id = '67'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

   echo $row['hobby'];

}
```

I wil get:

```
golf
baseball
golf
```

I want duplicate hobbies entered by the same person id to show only once, so it will show:

```
golf
baseball
```

And by duplicate I mean however many redundant times the same hobby by the same person is entered in a database (as long as it's more than once it should shown only once).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `hobby` FROM `hobbies` WHERE `person_id` = '67'");
```

`DISTINCT` will not show duplicates for `hobby`.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

Comment: doesn't work for me, it just returns nothing when I change * to DISTINCT. But even if that wasn't so I don't think this will do, because the same hobby by the same person will still be distinct in that there ids will be different as may the column "time".

Comment: oops sorry, I implemented it wrong, yes it does work. Best answer in 10 mins. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hobbies WHERE person_id = '67' GROUP BY hobby");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo $row['hobby'];
}
```